# Getting Exception Table is in read only mode intermittently

Tags: java, clickhouse

In my application while executing clickhouse insert query intermittently I am getting following exception

Code: 242, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Table is in readonly mode (version 19.14.6.12)

On clickhouse server error log at the same timestamp observed below exception.

````
0. 0x3353de0 StackTrace::StackTrace() /usr/bin/clickhouse
1. 0x66f25e8 ? /usr/bin/clickhouse
2. 0x66f2d0b Coordination::Exception::Exception(std::string const&, int) /usr/bin/clickhouse
3. 0x6708c75 Coordination::ZooKeeper::receiveThread() /usr/bin/clickhouse
4. 0x6708dc4 ? /usr/bin/clickhouse
5. 0x338cb43 ThreadPoolImpl<std::thread>::worker(std::_List_iterator<std::thread>) /usr/bin/clickhouse
6. 0x766d06f ? /usr/bin/clickhouse
7. 0x7fb7ac0f9dd5 start_thread /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
8. 0x7fb7aba1702d __clone /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
 (version 19.14.6.12)
2020.10.21 02:37:16.915321 [ 36 ] {} <Error> LeaderElection (/clickhouse/test_db/tables/1/test_db.manager_table/leader_election): Code: 999, e.displayText() = Coordination::Exception: Session expired (Session expired), Stack trace:

0. 0x3353de0 StackTrace::StackTrace() /usr/bin/clickhouse
1. 0x66f25e8 ? /usr/bin/clickhouse
2. 0x66f2d0b Coordination::Exception::Exception(std::string const&, int) /usr/bin/clickhouse
3. 0x6709074 Coordination::ZooKeeper::pushRequest(Coordination::ZooKeeper::RequestInfo&&) /usr/bin/clickhouse
4. 0x6709f87 Coordination::ZooKeeper::list(std::string const&, std::function<void (Coordination::ListResponse const&)>, std::function<void (Coordination::WatchResponse const&)>) /usr/bin/clickhouse
5. 0x66f8a91 zkutil::ZooKeeper::getChildrenImpl(std::string const&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&, Coordination::Stat*, std::function<void (Coordination::WatchResponse const&)>) /usr/bin/clickhouse
6. 0x66faa5c zkutil::ZooKeeper::tryGetChildren(std::string const&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&, Coordination::Stat*, std::shared_ptr<Poco::Event> const&) /usr/bin/clickhouse
7. 0x66faaea zkutil::ZooKeeper::getChildren(std::string const&, Coordination::Stat*, std::shared_ptr<Poco::Event> const&) /usr/bin/clickhouse
8. 0x6132a55 zkutil::LeaderElection::threadFunction() /usr/bin/clickhouse
9. 0x63f89f4 DB::BackgroundSchedulePoolTaskInfo::execute() /usr/bin/clickhouse
10. 0x63f95c2 DB::BackgroundSchedulePool::threadFunction() /usr/bin/clickhouse
11. 0x63f9624 ? /usr/bin/clickhouse
12. 0x338cb43 ThreadPoolImpl<std::thread>::worker(std::_List_iterator<std::thread>) /usr/bin/clickhouse
13. 0x766d06f ? /usr/bin/clickhouse
14. 0x7fb7ac0f9dd5 start_thread /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
15. 0x7fb7aba1702d __clone /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
 (version 19.14.6.12)
clickhouse-driver version
ru.yandex.clickhouse clickhouse-jdbc 0.1.54```


**clickhouse-server version**
19.14.6

This seems zookeeper issue, for same timestamp I verified zookeeper logs as well but no error observed. Let me know how can we fix this issue.
````

Answer (score 0):

19.14.6.12 is out of support.

It's a ZK issue. Check all Zookeepers.

It could be a network issue in communication CH with ZK.